# How to Store Check box in MYsql?

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, phpmyadmin

Am Newbie.I have this coding...How to store into Mysql and How to Retrieve from the Database?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="like" value="yes"/>Yes
<input type="checkbox" name="like" value="no"/>No
```

am doubt with if i select both 2 box means what will happen?
Please Explain...Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Just a question, shouldn't this be  a radio button instead of checkboxes. The values are 'Yes' and 'No' of the same checkbox and the user may select both. Usually 'Yes' and 'No' are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @Aziz: He's asking : `am doubt with if i select both 2 box means what will happen?` so he didn't know about radio buttons

Comment: @genesis sorry i missed that part, thanks for clearing it up

Comment: if you want to use checkboxes and only want to display one (yes case). ALWAYS add an hidden field by the same name for the "notchecked" value BEFOR the actual checkbox. so even if you are on an edit form, and the checkbox got unchecked, you get an value in your post which you otherwise wouldnt get.

Comment: If you want to use checkbox, e.g. allowing user to select multiple values (for example interests), then the name of the input have to be like[] - otherwise you will get only one value submited. As the other already answered, when you want user to select one option from multiple choises, you have to use radio  buttons or select dropdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have no problem with *comma separated values*

my answer will help you

simple use array name to your field

```
<input type="checkbox" name="like[]" value="yes"/>Yes
<input type="checkbox" name="like[]" value="no"/>No
```

then [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)  it with comma

```
implode(","$_POST['like']);
```

if two box is checked then
result will be `yes,no`

make your column in **varchar**
Then do usual stuff to store

Answer (score 1):

yourscript.php:

```
<?php
include("mysql_connect.php");
if ($_POST['like'])
{
    if ($_POST['like'] != "yes" and $_POST['like'] != "no") die("Hacker");
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO likes ('id', 'like') VALUES ('', '".$_POST['like']."')");
}
?>
<form method="post" action="yourscript.php">
<input type="checkbox" name="like" value="yes"/>Yes
<input type="checkbox" name="like" value="no"/>No 
</form>
```

retreive.php:

```
<?php
include("mysql_connect.php");
$likes = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM likes");
while($like = mysql_Fetch_assoc($likes))
{
   echo "ID ".$like['id']." => ".$like['like'];
}
```

If you select both fields, it will save the latest select. 
You want radio (probably)

Comment: it wont be correct.... first see the question top to bottom and reply... ur suggestion is wrong

Comment: @K6t: he's just asking WHAT WOULD happen, I know that if he selects both, it will insert  No. So it isn't wrong

Comment: do u know y i said wrong, if some one wanna asking same question they may try ur answer for that i said Wrong Dude..., cool

Comment: I am not talking to you anymore as I can't read your mess correctly

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to be doing this in the first place.  What you really want to be using is radio buttons for yes/no values.  Otherwise, you're going to run into problems.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="like[]" value="yes"/>Yes
<input type="checkbox" name="like[]" value="no"/>No
```

to store in db use `serialize();` function.

`unserialize()` return the same array with keys.